# Page expired due to inactivity in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel application(Laravel 5.6) which is currently running smoothly in the development environment. But when I shift it to the production environment it shows a message "The page has expired due to inactivity please refresh...". I have looked for solutions including increasing the **SESSION_LIFETIME** to 8 hours, including **csrf** in all my forms, but all to no avail. What else should I do to resolve this problem because at times the users of the system can be entering data and suddenly are logged out of the system and start all over again?

Sorry for asking a question that has been asked and answered so many times but seems not to be working for me.

I appreciate so much and thanks in advance

Comment: Did you run `php artisan key:generate` ?

Comment: Yes, i have done but the error still reappears

Comment: Well those changes are sometimes not affected immediately... I have experience when changing values inside config or .env file the best thing is to do is to restart the server or cache:clear and config:clear